# Take element of a Set collection depending on the value of another element

Tags: java, collections, set

I had to populate the fields of a `Service` object using a `Set` (HashSet) with any configuration parameters -> `ConfigurationMap` (Class with 2 attributes: key and value).
The problem is that the attribute `quantity` of `Service` object can be set from two distinct parameters ("service_quantity" or "publications_amount") based on the value of another parameter("type").

I've gotten it to work with the code below, but I think it's pretty messy and inefficient.
Is there any way to make it more readable considering that the methods signatures are invariable?

```
@Override
protected void populateServiceConfigurationData(Service theService, Set<ConfigurationMap> configurationParams) {
    boolean publishService = false;
    for (ConfigurationMap configParam : configurationParams) {
        String paramValue = configParam.getValue();
        String paramKey = configParam.getKey();
        setFieldValue(theService, paramKey, paramValue);
        if("type".equals(paramKey) && paramValue.equals("20")) {
            publishService = true;
        }
    }

    if(publishService) {
        for (ConfigurationMap configParam : configurationParams) {
            String paramKey = configParam.getKey();
            if(paramKey.equals("publications_amount")) {
                String paramValue = configParam.getValue();
                setFieldValue(theService, paramKey, paramValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void setFieldValue(Service service, String paramKey, String paramValue) {
    if ("type".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setType(Integer.valueOf(paramValue));
    }
    if ("service_quantity".equals(paramKey) || "publications_amount".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(paramValue));
    }
    if ("gateway_id".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setGatewayId(paramValue);
    }
    if ("comissions".equals(paramKey)) {
        service.setCommissions(paramValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tough one, hard to gain anything from introducing functions. I thought about introducing a `Set<String, Function>` or similar which maps from parameter names to setters on the service, but even that would add quite some overhead which is hardly worth the effort. I mean, if you're handling only these field names. If you have a hundred or so field names, I think the gains might be worth it to introduce such an infrastructure.

Comment: What you could do is find and store the value of "publications_amount" in the first loop, alongside "publish_service" and then set it inside the "publish"-loop directly. Then you don't need to do a second loop and the logic becomes a little bit easier to read, you can immediately see that "publications_amount" wins over "service_quantity" (or anything else) when publishing.

Comment: Doesn't the first loop already set `"publications_amount"` - and if so what is it for then (it's redundant)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it's pretty messy and inefficient

Let's say that it is getting messy, especially if the number of parameters (and hidden rules) keeps growing.

About being inefficient, I am not sure. Even if the input is very large, the method `populateServiceConfigurationData` runs in \$O(N)\$, so I don't think it will be a big problem.

My suggestions:

- **Readability**: setting the quantity of the service depends on more than one parameter. So the "rule" to set `quantity` would be more evident if included in a single function, like `setServiceQuantity`.
- **Performance**: the input set can be converted to a map, to easily access the parameters. The performance gain is minimal, but it should help to make the code more clear.
- **Design**: using `setFieldValue` in `populateServiceConfigurationData` seems unnecessary. The method `populateServiceConfigurationData` can be completely independent to `setFieldValue`. More on this later.

```java
public void populateServiceConfigurationData(Service service, Set<ConfigurationMap> configurationParams) {
    // Convert the input set to a map
    Map<String, String> params = configurationParams.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ConfigurationMap::getKey, ConfigurationMap::getValue));

    if (params.containsKey("type")) {
        service.setType(Integer.valueOf(params.get("type")));
    }

    if (params.containsKey("gateway_id")) {
        service.setGatewayId(params.get("gateway_id"));
    }

    if (params.containsKey("comissions")) {
        service.setCommissions(params.get("comissions"));
    }

    setServiceQuantity(service, params);
}

private void setServiceQuantity(Service service, Map<String, String> params){
    boolean isPublishService = params.get("type").equals("20");
    String quantity = isPublishService ? params.get("publications_amount") : params.get("service_quantity");
    service.setQuantity(Integer.valueOf(quantity));
}
```

(**Note**: not tested, it's just to give an idea)

Now the logic for setting each property of the service is clear and can be easily extracted into functions like `setServiceQuantity`.

One issue is that `populateServiceConfigurationData` needs to know how to set the properties into the service (for example, parsing `type` to `Integer`). If you don't like this approach, the setters can be replaced with `setFieldValue` (as before) or let `service` do the parsing in its own methods.

The method `setFieldValue` looks fine, the only thing I can suggest is to use `else if` since only one condition will match per invocation.

Comment: I like your approach but what if the number of parameters was higher in the future. Suppose there are 20 parameters, how this solution would scale?

Comment: It's still possible to loop over the map and set the fields of the service on the way, then calling `setServiceQuantity` at the end. Or I would look at [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) that allows the mapping between a map and a bean. Anyway, if the sole purpose of this class is to configure the service, it is ok to be a bit longer, as long as it is simple and easy to change.